# MySQL Query slow

Tags: mysql

I have an app that analyzes peoples facebook likes and matches them up with things they may have liked in past decades.

As part of refining the matches we have, I store each users likes (with a hash of their facebook ID, to keep it anonymous). People can enter multiple times, so it stores their likes multiple times, thus skewing the results a bit.

So my `user_likes` table is like this:

```
id  |  page_id   |  user_id_hash
----------------------------------
    |            |
```

I have around 820,000 records currently.

Currently if I do a query:

```
SELECT page_id, COUNT(*) from user_likes
GROUP BY page_id LIMIT 0,30
```

This takes around 8 seconds and gives me an incorrect count, since it can count people who entered multiple times more than once.

My questions are:

1) How can I speed this query up?
2) How can I get a more accurate count?

Comment: try executing this: `ALTER TABLE user_likes ADD INDEX page_id (page_id)` -- this will index column page_id.

Comment: I assume that speeds up the query right? I tried doing that and got a mysql error: `for the right syntax to use near 'KEY (page_id)' at line 1`

Comment: My bad, try it again. i mixed up the syntax. `ALTER TABLE user_likes ADD INDEX page_id (page_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a more accurate count by phrasing the query like this:

```
SELECT page_id, COUNT(distinct user_id_hash)
from user_likes ul
GROUP BY page_id LIMIT 0,30;
```

Speeding it up in MySQL is tricky, because of the `group by`.  You might try the following.  Create an index on `user_likes(page_id, user_id_hash)`.  Then try this:

```
select p.page_id,
       (select count(distinct user_id_hash)
        from user_likes ul
        where ul.page_id = p.page_id
       ) 
from (select distinct page_id
      from user_likes ul
     ) p
```

The idea behind this query is to avoid `group by` -- a poorly implemented operator in MySQL.  The inner query should use the index to get the list of unique `page_id`s.  The subquery in the select should use the same index for the count.  With the index-based operations, the count should go faster.

Comment: awesome thanks. And I assume I can append an `ORDER BY count(distinct user_id_hash) DESC`?

Comment: Also, I was wondering at what stage I'm going to run into trouble with amount of records? It's only been 1 day and I've got 820,000 records... This is meant to run for two months.

Comment: @ahren . . . I don't know.  If you are dealing with data from Facebook, be sure that you have the hardware to support it.